# Enzyme ignores certain prop values when testing React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Can anyone explain the following test in [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) for me?

`StateIdText.jsx`

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class StateIdTxt extends Component {
    propTypes: {
        x: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        y: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        stateId: PropTypes.number.isRequired
    }

    render() {
        const {x, y, stateId} = this.props;
        return (
                <text x={x} y={y}
                      textAnchor="end"
                      dominantBaseline="text-before-edge"
                      fontSize=".7em" fill="blue">
                    {stateId}
                </text>
        );
    }
}

export default StateIdTxt;
```

`StateIdTxt.test.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import {mount, render, shallow} from 'enzyme';

import StateIdTxt from './StateCoordTxt.jsx';

it('shallow <StateIdTxt />', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<StateIdTxt x={1.5} y={2.1} stateId={99} />);
    expect(wrapper.prop('x')).toEqual(1.5);
    expect(wrapper.prop('y')).toEqual(2.1);
    expect(wrapper.prop('stateId')).toBeUndefined();

    expect(wrapper.prop('textAnchor')).toBe('start'); // how come not end?
    expect(wrapper.prop('dominantBaseline')).toBe('text-before-edge');
    expect(wrapper.prop('fontSize')).toBe('.7em');
    expect(wrapper.prop('fill')).toBe('blue');
});
```

Why does `wrapper.prop('textAnchor')` expect a 'start', which it passes, instead of 'end'? I can actually change 'end' to other random text, and the test still passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the filenames you mentioned in your post, I think you have a typo in an import in `StateIdTxt.test.js`:

```
import StateIdTxt from './StateCoordTxt.jsx';
```

Looks like it should be

```
import StateIdTxt from './StateIdTxt.jsx';
```